# What side is a newborn supposed to nurse from first?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, talmud-gemara, children-parenting, baby-infant

I have heard that there is a gemara that discusses what side a newborn is supposed to breastfeed from first.

If this is true, where is this gemara and what's the idea behind it?

Comment: FWIW, I searched my ( *poorly OCR'ed* ) English Ein Yaakov for the word "nurs" ....didn't find anything that seemed relevant to your question.

Comment: A newborn is supposed to nurse from the front.

Comment: @Shokhet try _suckl_.

Comment: http://www.chabadmineola.com/1856236 says the left side, seemingly quoting an earlier source as saying it's "close to the heart", but doesn't cite that source (or any other).

Comment: It's the left side - but I'm having trouble finding a source...

Comment: @msh210 I tried "*suckl*;" got a few hits that I didn't get before, but no answers to this question. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

The [Kaf HaChaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Chaim_Sofer) writes in [Yoreh Deah siman 116 number 149](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9081&st=&pgnum=301) "a woman that begins to nurse her son should begin nursing from the left breast first". He writes that his source is the Tzava'as Rebbe Yehudah HaChasid #69 and the sefer Shmiras HaNefesh #17.

The sefer [Mishnas Yehoshua](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51580&st=%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%94&pgnum=131) footnote #18 (on the linked page) mentions that according to the sefer Shmiras HaGuf Ve'haNefesh, a person does not have to be concerned to do this with a daughter (only with a son).