# Source for an Aggadah about Moshe feeding a bird

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, moshe-rabbeinu, agada-stories-legends, birds

I was reading a book called "Shylock" by Hermann Sinsheimer and he made reference to a story from "the Jewish Talmud." (can be seen [here](https://archive.org/details/shylockthehistor010431mbp/page/n79/mode/2up?q=talmud)) I don't know to what he is referring. I looked online quickly and found someone else, in 1996, asking the same question (it is an old book...I'm just getting around to it). I will copy the salient parts of the question and the answer: (from http://shaksper.net/archive/1996/126-june/4318-no-subject)

> On June 6 Jacob Goldberg asked where in the Talmud one could find the
> following story quoted by H. Sinsheimer in his book on Shylock.
>
> "In the Talmud, there is a legend about Moses coming down from Sinai
> and seeing an eagle carrying a lamb in its beak.  In a rage, Moses
> upbraids the eagle for being about to kill a fellow animal, just when
> he, Moses, had received the commandment of God: Thou shalt not kill!
> The eagle drops its prey, but comes down to Moses, asking him to feed
> its young himself.  At this, the holy man bares his breast and offers
> his own flesh to the bird of prey."
>
> "Sefer HaAgadah" by Bialik and Ravnitzky, (Dvir (Hebrew), Tel Aviv, 3d
> edition 1948) is an indexed compendium of Talmudic tales metaphors and
> aphorisms, which I have no reason to believe is not exhaustive. I
> looked up all the references where "eagle" and "Moses" appeard on the
> same page and came up with nothing. The tale is probably spurious,
> especially since a good deal the Law given to the Moses deals with the
> regulation of animal sacrifice.  The commandment should read in
> English "Thou shalt not commit murder", rather than "Thou shalt not
> kill".  It seems that the translators of the King James Bible seem to
> have taken great pains to maintain the number of words as close to the
> Hebrew original as possible and even their order, presumably out of
> respect for its sanctity.  In the Hebrew the commandment is stated in
> a mere two words.  (Such restraints on the translation would justify
> using the best English wordsmiths around - lending weight to the
> proposition that Shakespeare was on the team.)
>
> ...
>
> Quoting sources is a solid Rabbinic tradition going back 2000 years,
> as is adherence to rules of derivation.  Therefore I would suggest
> that Sinsheimer's failure to supply tractate and page imply that there
> is none. On the other hand, maybe it wasn't an eagle but some other
> bird.  No one I have asked has heard of the story but I will keep
> looking."

Does anyone know of a source for this story which might have escaped the author of this web-response and which could have been to what Sinsheimer was referring?

Comment: A search for "*eagle*" in [my English Ein Yaakov](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50572/what-side-is-a-newborn-supposed-to-nurse-from-first#comment133459_50572) didn't find anything similar to this story.

Comment: This story sounds very Christian, I.e. extreme literalist moral interpretation of the Torah.

Comment: What's the end of the story? I mean, it obviously didn't eat up Moses. So how did it feed its young?

Comment: Doesn't seem true. I never heard of any Talmudic or Midrashic stories that involved people (other than Billam)  talking to animals in ANY context.. And of course as the OP says the story makes no sense because the Torah does not forbid killing animals for food

Comment: @Schmerel There's Shlomo telling the eagle to bring him the Shamir. And I think there's one where Yonah talks to the fish who swallowed him.